# TCL no such file or directory

Tags: tcl

I am running this script nmrCube.tcl for generating 3D box from NMR data.

I initially had problem with Library before which is now sorted

While running the script I get this, (even though it is indeed there):

> Error in startup script: couldn't read file "“./nmrCube.tcl”": no such file or directory

Comment: Is your nmrCube.tcl file in the same directory as from where you are trying to run the script? `./` means the current working directory you are in.

Comment: There might be an obvious error which I can not see.

Comment: Are the `“`, `”` quotes really a part of the error message? If so, they've probably slipped into your code as in `open “./nmrCube.tcl”`, and you need to remove them.

Comment: Yes they are part of the error message. 
But unsure how to get rid of them since I do ./nmrCube.tcl to execute the script Thanks

Comment: You have to remove them from the invocation you are using. If you are using for instance `source “./nmrCube.tcl”` you need to change that to `source ./nmrCube.tcl`.

Comment: What is the first line of the script?

Comment: Don't use curly quotes in your script. Use straight quotes.

Comment: duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/678958/10127

Answer (score 4):

Tcl regards `“`curly quotes`”` as entirely ordinary characters. They're not alphanumerics or one of Tcl's metacharacters, so they follow the same basic rules as characters like `/` and `.` and so on.

You probably don't want to use them in a Tcl script except in text for display to the user. You might want to use the `"`straight quotes`"` instead, which are metacharacters for Tcl. If your editor insists on converting those to fancy quotes, *find another text editor*. (You'd have problems using it for virtually any other programming language as well.)